# Dash bar icons clickable area

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04

I just switched to Ubuntu 22.04 and noticed that if the mouse cursor is up against the left edge of the screen, the dock icons are not clickable, unlike Ubuntu 20.04 where they were.

Note that this seems to only occur with Ubuntu's dock; disabling the "Ubuntu Dock" GNOME Extension and using GNOME's native dash bar in the activities overview works even if the cursor is against the bottom screen edge.

This may seem like a minor gripe but honestly it's already getting annoying, especially when using a touchpad and the dock auto-hide feature (since revealing the dock requires going up against the screen's edge). It feels like an unnecessary regression.

Does anyone know how to change the clickable area so it behaves more like it used to?

### Ubuntu 20.04

[image: Ubuntu 20.04]

### Ubuntu 22.04

[image: Ubuntu 22.04]

[image: Ubuntu 22.04 (against side of screen)]

Comment: May work more like expected in Xorg. This is worth filing as a bug.

Comment: @vanadium what would the appropriate procedure be for reporting?

Comment: I guess on launchpad for Ubuntu. Perhaps also with the developper of the extension Dash To Dock, provided the issue also occurs on other distributions.

Comment: Agreed, this is a blatant violation of Fitt's Law (https://blog.codinghorror.com/fitts-law-and-infinite-width/), and a big step back in usability. Ironically, there's a "Panel mode" setting that "extends the dock to the screen edge", which is now entirely cosmetic with this change.